# golang cannot add a package

Tags: go, package, vendor

I am trying to add the godotenv package to my working project.

I run

```
go get github.com/joho/godotenv
```

from the command line. This inserts the dependency into my `go.mod` file, which now looks like this:

```
...
github.com/joho/godotenv v1.5.1
...
```

VScode flags this as an error and says

```
github.com/joho/godotenv is not used in this module
```

and asks me to run `go mod tidy`. But if I do that, it removes the dependency from go.mod

Alternatively, I add the import

```
"github.com/joho/godotenv"
```

to the module where I want to use it (`main.go`)

VScode then reports an error

```
could not import github.com/joho/godotenv (no required module provides package "github.com/joho/godotenv")compilerBrokenImport
```

and as a quick fix advises me to run

```
go get github.com/joho/godotenv
```

However, if I do this, the same error appears in `go.mod`.

And if I save the main.go file, the import is automatically removed. So this seems to be going round in circles.

Further information: I have a vendors folder, which is required by heroku where I am currently hosting the project. I tried running

```
go mod vendor
```

at each of the points in the above cycle, but the problem persists.

What sequence of actions will install this package for me?

Comment: Use the package in your code (either real or through a blank import) and run go mod tidy. If you do not actually _use_ a package it's removed.

Answer (score 0):

It's ever happen to me. I use function in code and import it then go mody tidy && go mod vendor

try use it once in your code.

```
godotenv.Load()
```

and import it and run  go mody tidy && go mod vendor again.

Comment: Hi shosae and thanks. Actually, I should have said that I also tried this, because it has worked for me in the past when I encountered this type of issue. But this time at least, the result was no different: VScode doesn't accept the import. I then have two choices - save it, in which case VScode removes the import, or accept the advice of the Quick Fix and run go get. 

I figure that the underlying problem is VScode won't save the file while the import statement is in it, so go mod tidy of course says 'hey, you aren't using this, so I won't let you include it in your module.